# Yii2: Orientation doens't work (Kartik's ExportMenu)

Tags: pdf, yii2, export, orientation, landscape

I want to use the [kartik-v/yii2-export](https://packagist.org/packages/kartik-v/yii2-export) widget to generate a landscape PDF file but `orientation` property is not working:

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'codigo_polinomica',
        'descripcion',
        'unidad_medida',
    ],
    'exportConfig' => [
        \kartik\export\ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => [
            'pdfConfig' => [
                'orientation' => 'L',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

ExportMenu works great but the problem is only with the orientation.

I installed yii2-export: `require kartik-v/yii2-export "dev-master"`.
Do I need to install something else?

Update (this works):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'orientation' => 'L'
    ]);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>This is just a <strong>test</strong></p>');
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: your code looks to be correct can you try a standalone call to mpdf with the configurations like `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => [190, 236],
    'orientation' => 'L'
]);` and see what it outputs?

Comment: Sorry. Where should I write that code? Do you have a larger example?

Comment: in any of the controllers you have you can write the above piece of code into your action and refresh , just remember to call the `->output()` to generate the file and then check, like for example `$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>This is just a <strong>test</strong>, This is just a <strong>test</strong></p>');
$mpdf->Output();`, make sure you are saving the class instance in the `$mpdf`

Comment: Great. That works. And now how can I use yii2-export?